# Do external storage devies (e.g., USB harddrives/flash thumbdrives) have a unique ID accessible from Windows Cmd?

Tags: cmd

Do external storage devices (e.g., USB harddrives/flash thumbdrives) have a unique ID accessible from the Command line in Windows?  (including WMIC and Powershell).

By "unique" I mean something that is not assigned by the Format operation or by the particular OS it's on (e.g., System Device ID), since these devices are regularly reformatted or swapped between computers.   I'm looking for something supplied by the manufacturer or in the hardware.

Purpose -  we have a stack of external storage devices where we're seeing wide differences in performance during backup operations.   All backups are centrally-logged via a batch file so we're keeping statistics to study this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wmic diskdrive get caption,serialnumber
```

The serial number alone might not be unique (different vendors might use the same format and by chance the same serial numbers)

Comment: Thanks!   I had considered serialnumber but in the case of LogicalDiskDrive the serial number is assigned during the Format and I didn't realise it was different with DiskDrive.

Comment: wmic `diskdrive` is the actual physical drive. `logicaldrive` is the drive as it is presented to the OS (sometimes referenced as `volume` or `partition`).